# Retrieve LOGs in Between Entries Where Process takes More Than Certain Period of Time - Graylog

Tags: graylog

I'm wondering whether is possible to apply a query in a batch process's LOG  where we can identify LOGs entries that takes more than a certain period of time to be printed out after the previous one.

**e.g.** an entry that represents a SQL or Command is printed out and the next one will only be printed after 5 or 10 minutes depending on how much time is specified in the query statement.

**P.s.:** We know we could measure the time being spent by a certain process (SQL or Command) including some codes to capture those information but we're analyzing LOGs from a week ago.